# QtWebkit and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, qt, qtwebkit

I'm having problems with getting `QTWebKit` to properly handling ASP.NET websites.

For example, the menu bar example on the page http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx is not working.

Any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

what version of Qt you're using? I've just check that site on Qt 4.7.4 Fancy Browser demo and everything works well for me